# Expansion of nonlinear functions with damping properties in exponential series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, approximation-theory, integral-transforms, nonlinear-dynamics

I am working on solving nonlinear differential equations and found such a solution with exponential properties.
$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{d}{dx}(sech(x)^2)$

The solution of which is:

$x(t) = \sinh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{LambertW\left(e^{c_1-4 t}\right)}\right)$

where $c_1$ - arbitrary constant.

Let's assume that $c_1 = 20$.

```
Plot[{ArcSinh[Sqrt[ProductLog[Exp[20 - 4 t]]]]}, {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

**If we assume that this signal contains an exponential component, a nonlinear wave component that distorts this signal, then the question arises: is it possible to expand the solution of the differential equation in a series of exponentials that would approximate the solution to the equation well?**

$ProbablyQuasiSolution = e^{-p_1 \cdot t} + e^{-p_2 \cdot t} ... e^{-p_n \cdot t}$

Some of the components that, in my opinion, are present in the solution, I reflected in the second plot.

```
Plot[{ArcSinh[Sqrt[ProductLog[Exp[20 - 4 t]]]], 2.12 Exp[-t], 
  ArcSinh[Sqrt[ProductLog[Exp[20 - 4 t]]]] - 2.12 Exp[-t], 
  6.4 (Exp[-1/2 t] - Exp[-1 t])}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/229190/edit

Comment: $x(t)=X(e^{c_1-4t})$. If you find a power series of $X(z)$ then you have your series of exponentials.

Comment: Expanding about $z=0$ is like expanding about $t=+\infty$. I just went for two terms and got some very nice results.

Comment: I expanded the function into a Taylor series and the result was not very pleasing to me.
$\sqrt{e^{20-4 t}}-\frac{2}{3} \left(e^{20-4 t}\right)^{3/2}$

https://ibb.co/0DWNBBd

Comment: That will work well for large $t$. It will be poor for small $t$ because $c$ is so large. $e^{20}$ is massive! Try $c=0$ or $c=1$.

Comment: That's it! Therefore, this decision did not suit me.

Comment: Then expand around different points. The approximations will only be valid for small regions though. You could expand about $z=e$, but with such a large value I cannot imagine it would be valid for many $t$, but give it a go. I think with such a large argument, you will struggle to get a good approximation. Also, if you zoom in on that picture you will find it to be an excellent approximation for $t>5$.

Comment: The answer might help deal with large constants better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you went through the steps
$$t'=-\frac{1}{2} \cosh ^2(x) \coth (x)$$
$$t+c=-\frac{1}{8} \cosh (2 x)-\frac{1}{2} \log (\sinh (x))$$ Using $y=\sinh(x)$
$$t+c=-\frac{y^2}{4}-\frac{\log (y)}{2}-\frac{1}{8}$$
$$y=\pm \sqrt{k\, W\left(e^{-4 t}\right)}\implies x=\sinh ^{-1}\left(\pm\sqrt{k\, W\left(e^{-4 t}\right)}\right)$$

Let $z=e^{-4 t}$ and expand around $z=0$ to get (for the $+$ branch)
$$x=\sqrt k \sqrt z \left(1-\frac{k+3}6 z+\frac{ 3 k^2+10 k+25} {40}z^2-\frac { 15 k^3+63 k^2+147 k+343}{336}z^3+O\left(z^4\right)\right)$$ and you face a linear combination of powers of $e^{-2t}$.

Comment: It's a Taylor series?

Comment: @dtn. Yes it is. What else could it be with $O(z^4)$ ? Cheers :-)

Comment: and there are analogues of the Taylor series, for which more compact forms of notation have been developed?