# Nonlinear quasi-exponential functions

Tags: exponential-function, laplace-transform, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics

I continue the study of gradient differential equations, where bell-shaped functions are used as a function, for example:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{d}{dx}(sech(x)^2)$

The solution of which is:

$x(t) = \sinh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{LambertW\left(e^{c_1-4 t}\right)}\right)$

where $c_1$ - arbitrary constant.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_shaped_function

[Expansion of nonlinear functions with damping properties in exponential series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3811394/expansion-of-nonlinear-functions-with-damping-properties-in-exponential-series)

Let's assume that $c_1 = 20$.

[image]

[image]

It can be seen that the solution of such differential equations shows a transition from the initial state to the maximum / minimum point. This transient process is described by a rather complex nonlinear function.
I conclude that either an exponential process is at the heart of such a function, over which a nonlinear transformation is performed, or such a transient process is the sum of an exponential process and a wave similar to a lognormal distribution.

I am interested in the following questions:

1. Are there more or less developed functions of quasi-exponential processes?
2. Are there more flexible analogs of the lognormal distribution, allowing more fine tuning of its shape, and over which the Laplace transform can be easily performed.